# jQuery value of a textbox child inside a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox inside of a drop down with no id or name.  I need to be get the value of the textbox.  How do I do that?  Here is what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/gfinzer/otqydwru/1/

```
<select id="ddlInsuranceCompany" name="insuranceCompany">
    <option value="1">America First</option>
    <option value="1">Indiana</option>
    <option value="1">Peerless</option>
    <input type="text" value="Test" />
</select>
```

```js
var myValue = $('#ddlInsuranceCompany').children(':text').first().val();
alert(myValue);
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - an `input` cannot be a child element of a `select`. If you inspect the DOM you'll see that the browser has automatically fixed this by moving the input to a valid location. `myValue` is empty because `.children(':text')` is not finding the element in the DOM

Comment: As Rory said your HTML is invalid... but if you still wanna get value of textbx you can do this `var myValue = $('input[type="text"]').val();`  kindly check updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/otqydwru/2/

Comment: @RRR OP is specifically says that it should be inside the `select`. As per you fiddle it will select all the `textbox`

Comment: The problem is that this is 3rd party autocomplete control.  The input text is inside the select.  Yes it is invalid.  Yes the option values are duplicate.  That is just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid - an `input` cannot be a child element of a `select`. If you inspect the DOM you'll see that the browser has automatically fixed this by moving the input to a valid location. `myValue` is empty because `.children(':text')` is not finding the element in the DOM.

To fix this issue you could amend the HTML yourself by placing the `input` after the `select` and using `next()` to retrieve it. Try this:

```
<select id="ddlInsuranceCompany" name="insuranceCompany">
    <option value="1">America First</option>
    <option value="1">Indiana</option>
    <option value="1">Peerless</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="Test" />
```

```js
var myValue = $('#ddlInsuranceCompany').next(':text').val();
console.log(myValue);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/otqydwru/3/)

Comment: It is a 3rd party auto complete control that is adding the input text type to the dom inside the selector.  It is invalid.  That is just the mess I am in.

Comment: The code above still works with the invalid HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/otqydwru/3/. You should contact the creator of that plugin though, as that's a pretty obvious error.